# I want to completely remove titlebars from windows

Tags: compiz, themes, elementary-theme, window-decoration

I want to completely remove titlebars from windows...but still have shadows via window decorations.

I am using the [Elementary borderless theme](http://bobdmv.deviantart.com/art/Elementary-borderless-v0-2-5-192767462) and Compiz. But it doesn't matter too much which theme I use, I suppose. Basically I want to get rid of all window decorations except for the shadows.

What should I look for in my theme file to get rid of the titlebars? Or is there a better way?

I'd rather not use Emerald or another window manager right now.

I mainly use keyboard shortcuts for all window activities.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the [compizconfig-settings-manager[image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) package.
2. Open *CompizConfig Settings Manager* and navigate to the *Window Decoration* plugin.

   [image]
3. Change the value of the *Decoration windows* entry to `none`:

   [image]

Comment: excellent. I had to restart compiz form shadows to come back. thanks!

Comment: gnome-terminal no longer has a shadow, even after making an exception for it. hmm